# How to detect the first word and include it in a string replacement line in python?

Tags: python

I want to read a column where the first word in each row is the quarter, and year the survey was taken, as well as the name of the survey. Initially I was trying to rename the survey name where I was keeping the quarter and year constant throughout the column but if I ran this script against files from other quarters then the whole line would not be detected and my script would not work.

My example:

```
        Survey Name
0       Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech
1       Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech
2       Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech
3       Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech
4       Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech
                
9630    Q321 Your Voice - Business Group
9631    Q321 Your Voice - Business Group
```

(Q321 = Quarter 3, 2021)

What my code converts it into:

```
Survey Name
0       Q321 YV - IT
1       Q321 YV - IT
2       Q321 YV - IT
3       Q321 YV - IT
4       Q321 YV - IT
                
9630    Q321 YV - BG
9631    Q321 YV - BG
```

The code I use:

```
print(df.loc[:, "Survey.Name"])

'isolate to column of interest and replace commonly incorrect string with the correct output'

df.loc[df['Survey.Name'].str.contains('Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech'), 'Survey.Name'] = \
    'Q321 YV - IT'

df.loc[df['Survey.Name'].str.contains('Q321 Your Voice - Business Group'), 'Survey.Name'] = \
    'Q321 YV - BG'

df.loc[df['Survey.Name'].str.contains('Q321 Your Voice - Study Group'), 'Survey.Name'] = \
    'Q321 YV - SG'
        
    
print(df.loc[:, "Survey.Name"])
```

But say that I run this script against a file from a different quarter, say Quarter 4, 2021:

```
Survey Name
0       Q421 Your Voice - Information Tech
1       Q421 Your Voice - Information Tech
2       Q421 Your Voice - Information Tech
3       Q421 Your Voice - Information Tech
4       Q421 Your Voice - Information Tech

9630    Q421 Your Voice - Business Group
9631    Q421 Your Voice - Business Group
```

I would have to change my script every time a new quarter is used. Is there a way for me to "detect" the first word which luckily happens to be the quarter and year of the survey and include it in the transformed version, whilst also replacing the string that requires to be changed in that column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, perhaps over-complicated, approach is to use a regex with capture groups as below:

```
res = df["Survey Name"].str.replace(r"(Q\d+)\s+(\w)\w+ (\w)\w+ - (\w)\w+ (\w)\w+", r"\1 \2\3 - \4\5", regex=True)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    Q321 YV - IT
1    Q321 YV - IT
2    Q321 YV - IT
3    Q321 YV - IT
4    Q321 YV - IT
5    Q321 YV - BG
6    Q321 YV - BG
Name: Survey Name, dtype: object
```

Note that the regex pattern captures the first word and the first letter of each of the remaining words.

Another alternative is to use apply, with a replacement function:

```
def repl(x):
    head, tail = x.split("-")
    quarter, *chunk = head.split()

    head_initials = "".join(c[0] for c in chunk)
    tail_initials = "".join(c[0] for c in tail.split())

    return f"{quarter} {head_initials} - {tail_initials}"


res = df["Survey Name"].apply(repl)
```

**Output**

```
0    Q321 YV - IT
1    Q321 YV - IT
2    Q321 YV - IT
3    Q321 YV - IT
4    Q321 YV - IT
5    Q321 YV - BG
6    Q321 YV - BG
Name: Survey Name, dtype: object
```

**UPDATE**

A more general approach to the replacement part is to do:

```
replacements = {
    "Your Voice - Information Tech": "YV - IT Group",
    "Your Voice - Business Group": "YV - BG",
    "Your Voice - Human Resources": "YV - LRECS"
}


def repl(match, repls=replacements):
    quarter = match.group(1)
    key = " ".join(match.group(2).strip().split())

    return f"{quarter} {replacements.get(key, '')}"


res = df["Survey Name"].str.replace(r"(Q\d+)\s+(.+)", repl, regex=True)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
0    Q321 YV - IT Group
1    Q321 YV - IT Group
2    Q321 YV - IT Group
3    Q321 YV - IT Group
4    Q321 YV - IT Group
5          Q321 YV - BG
6       Q321 YV - LRECS
Name: Survey Name, dtype: object
```

Note that `replacements` is a dictionary where the keys are the string expected to be found and the values the corresponding replacements.

The data for the output above was generated from:

```
{'Survey Name': {0: 'Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech',
                 1: 'Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech',
                 2: 'Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech',
                 3: 'Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech',
                 4: 'Q321 Your Voice - Information Tech',
                 5: 'Q321 Your Voice - Business Group',
                 6: 'Q321 Your Voice - Human Resources'}}
```

Comment: Ok so your code works for my dataframe, thank you! I was wondering if I can ask how can it be tweaked so that I can choose to replace the "Your Voice - Information Tech" to "YV - IT Group" , essentially, I don't necessarily want to replace the survey string with initials, but with the string that I choose, the part that detects the Quarter and Year works as intended.

Comment: @Scythor So you want Group only for IT? Or also for BG?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is IT, BG, HR or any other business group I don't necessarily want to transform the names into initials, I want to transform the names into what I set it as. Like if the group name is "Human Resources" I want it to be named "LRECS" according to my str replacement code.

Comment: So your code works perfectly for detecting which Quarter and Year the dataframe is from and it would keep the Quarter and Year when replacing the string, because if I used a different dataframe where the column is "Q421 Your Voice - Human Resources", changing "Human Resources" to LRECS is done by using `df.loc[df['Survey.Name'].str.contains('Q321 Your Voice - Human Resources'), 'Survey.Name'] = 'Q321 YV - LRECS'`

it would always replace Q421 to Q321 but the survey name would change to what I want it to be. So in a way i'm asking if there is a way to combine your code with my code.

Comment: @Scythor See the updated answer

Comment: `regex` is really how I would go about it, so I would not consider it over complicated.

Comment: @DaniMesejo apologies if I keep coming back, you totally understood what I needed. I tried replicating this code and tailored it to my dataframe which is has slightly different syntax in the replacement variable, but the output only seems to give the Quarter Year. I am trying it on a Q122 dataframe and it prints the "Q122" part but the rest is empty, the repl part is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I got everything right but I think you can simply use `split` for this:

Example:

```py
t = "9631    Q421 Your Voice - Business Group".split()
print(t)
print(t[1])
# prints ['9631', 'Q421', 'Your', 'Voice', '-', 'Business', 'Group']
# prints 'Q421'
```

Comment: Ah, the numbers on the left are just index reference numbers (separate column). 
Also this wouldn't detect other quarters and years like Q221 or Q122, Q222. I want this part to be detected from the dataframe and added to the column and the rest of the text to be replaced. So if the dataframe read Q223 (Quarter 2, 2023) from the survey name column, e.g. "Q223 Your Voice - Information Tech" or "Q422 Your voice - Information Tech" , the "QXYY" is always detected rather than replaced and the rest of the string is replaced since it is always the same string, just different quarter and year.